# From Riemannian curvature to Ricci curvature in warped product manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-curvature

Let $M=B \times_f F$ be a warped product of two pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. If $X, Y, Z \in L(B)$ and $U, V, W \in L(F)$, (with $L(B)$ and $ L(F)$ I mean the set of all horizontal and vertical lift to M), then we have:

(1) $R(V, W)U = {R(V, W)U}^F +
\frac{\langle \nabla f, \nabla f \rangle }{f^2}(\langle V, U \rangle W − \langle W, U \rangle V )$

(with ${R(V, W)U}^F$ is lift to $M$ to the curvature tensor of $F$).

and Ricci curvature:

(2) $\operatorname{Ric}(V, W)={\operatorname{Ric}(V,W)}^F-(\frac{\Delta f}{f}+(k-1)\frac{\langle \nabla f , \nabla f \rangle }{f^2})\langle V,W \rangle$.
(where $k$ is the dimension of $F$).

From (1) to (2), $k$ turns out (which is the dimension of the fiber manifold) and will be due to some trace, but I don't understand if it will be a trace where they get $k$ and then they find something like:

$k \frac{\langle \nabla f, \nabla f \rangle }{f^2}-\frac{\langle \nabla f, \nabla f \rangle }{f^2}$, then:

$(k-1)\frac{\langle \nabla f, \nabla f \rangle }{f^2}$.

Or a trace in which a dimension is excluded for some reason, therefore not get $k$, but $k-1$, then $(k-1)\frac{\langle \nabla f, \nabla f \rangle }{f^2}$.

How is that $(k-1)$ found?

Comment: I would try working out the case when both $B$ and $F$ have dimension $1$.

Comment: Write everything in terms of an orthonormal basis of $T_bB$ and another one of $T_fF$, and take the trace. A related observation is that the Ricci curvature of the $n$-sphere is $\mathrm{Rc}(V,W) = (n-1)g(V,W)$.

Comment: The n-sphere, $S^n$, with the round metric is Einstein with  $k=n-1$, i.e. $Ric=kg$, then $Ric=(n-1)g$. Now if we take the trace we have:$R=n(n-1)$. Then for n-Sphere $(n-1)$ is the constant $k$, not the result of the trace.

Comment: The skew symmetry of the Riemann curvature tensor causes one of the terms in the trace to vanish. That's also why the Ricci curvature of the unit $k$-sphere is $k-1$ and not $k$.

Comment: This is all easier to see if you write the Riemann curvatures with respect to an orthonormal bases of the base, fiber, and product. The curvature components in the fiber directions contain a term like $$ \frac{\langle\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle}{f^2}(\delta_{ij}\delta_{ab}-\delta_{ia}\delta_{jb})$$
When you take the trace over the indices $a$ and $b$, you get the $k-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using (1), the relevant trace is the following, where $e_1, \dots, e_k$ is an orthonormal frame on $F$:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Ric}(V,W) &= \cdots - \sum_{i=1}^k \langle e_i, R(V,e_i)W\rangle\\
&=
\cdots - \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{\langle\nabla f,\nabla f\rangle}{f^2}(\langle e_i,e_i\rangle\langle V,W\rangle - \langle V, e_i\rangle\langle W,e_i\rangle)
\end{align*}

Comment: Dear prof. Yang, and how does the term $\frac{\Delta f}{f}$ come out?

Answer (score 1):

In Besse "Einstein Manifold" in Corollary 9.105 you can find:

[image]

Here, you can guess how (9.105c), (9.105e) and (9.105d) can contribute to (9.106a) which is yours (2).